# Attaching listener to dialog

Tags: android

I need to be notified when there are changes on the screen. Currently I am using

```
this.getWindow().getDecorView().getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout()
            {
                Log.d("TAG", "GLOBAL LAYOUT");
            }
        });
```

But it doesn't work when dialog(custom, alert, progress, etc.) is shown or dismissed. I understand that dialogs are shown on another overlay so listener isn't attached to them. How can I get my desired functionality?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need a dialog.setOnDismissListener or dialog.setOnCancelListener

They'll be called when something related to dialog dismissal happens or is being canceled.

Comment: no, that is not the case. Maybe I can access that overlay somehow?